# Skype font size

Tags: skype

Ever since Microsoft spend 9 Billion to buy Skype, they have been messing with it making it less and less user friendly.

End of Rant !

How do I change Font size in Chat window, it is ridiculously small..

[image: font]

Skype version 8.30.0.50 on MacBook Air HighSierra

PS here is an example of arrogant answer ..

```
Changing font size using the new Skype is currently not available. You will be using the default font size whenever using the new Skype version.
Susan_S.
Skype Community Moderator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the only option available (laughable)

To change font size, try these keyboard shortcuts:

```
Cmd + Shit + for zoom in
Cmd + - for zoom out
Cmd + 0 for actual size
```

Of course if you zoom in the entire Skype window zooms in.